# LESS Weighted average of two colors

Tags: css, colors, less

In LESS there is a function that computes the average of two colors. For example,

```
average(#ff6600, #666666);
```

outputs `#b36633`.

But this function takes equal parts of `color1` and `color2`. Is there a way to say, take X% of `color1` and (1-X)% of `color2` and average them?

Of course, no such function exists. But maybe through the help of some other functions, we can achieve a weighted average?

**EDIT**: I think using `mix()` may take care of it, since you can specify a percentage proportion:

```
mix(#ff6600, #666666, 70%)
```

However, I'm not sure if `mix(color1, color2, 50%)` would achieve the same effect as `average(color1, color2)` for any `color1`, `color2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mix(#ff6600, #666666, 70%)` for the last parameter 0% will result in the first color we stated (which in this case `ff6600)` while 100% will do the `666666.`

so in your case `mix(color1, color2, 70%)` the output is 70% of color2 plus 30% of color1.

the default is 50% if you leave the parameter empty!